# Setting up phpmyadmin with traefik2 in docker

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, traefik

I am having some trouble accessing my phpmyadmin through traefik2 reverse proxy! all the other apps I am using in my docker-compose are working correctly through traefik. Its as simple as setting the labels up, specififying which domain to use, and then going to that through a browser. Right now I am able to access phpmyadmin through the local ip and port, but unable to through my domain. I just get a 404 not found error. This is my phpmyadmin docker-compose setup.

```
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
#    volumes:
#      - $USERDIR/docker/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
    environment:
      - PMA_PORT=$DB_PORT
      - PMA_HOST=$MYSQL_HOST
#      - PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=$ABSOLUTE_URI
#      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - $PHPMYADMIN_PORT:80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
#      - "traefik.backend=phpmyadmin"
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-rtr.rule=Host(`phpmyadmin.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-rtr.middlewares=chain-oauth@file"
      ## HTTP Services
      - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-rtr.service=phpmyadmin-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.phpmyadmin-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

I am also getting a very similar error with my php/apache container that I can access locally but not through traefik. All the other containers have been a simple swap of the labels, rename them and boom, they are accessible ! what am I doing wrong? I tried adding PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=$ABSOLUTE_URI and I can't figure out how to enable ssl in phpmyadmin in docker.

and it still doesnt work but phpmyadmin says:

> There is a mismatch between HTTPS indicated on the server and client. This can lead to a non working phpMyAdmin or a security risk. Please fix your server configuration to indicate HTTPS properly.

And also for my apache server it is setup like this, with a similar problem where it can be accessed from localhost but not traefik!

```
  apache:
    build:
      context: $USERDIR/docker/apache
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache
    volumes:
      - $USERDIR/WEBSITE:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 6546:80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache-rtr.entrypoints=https"
#      - "traefik.http.routers.tautulli-rtr.rule=Host(`web.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache-rtr.rule=Host(`$SECONDDOMAINNAME`)"
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache-rtr.middlewares=chain-no-auth@file"
      ## HTTP Services
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache-rtr.service=apache-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.apache-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

sorry if this is alot, I am very new to docker, and really trying to figure this out! If i posted this in the wrong spot or something, let me know!

and if you need anymore information, please also let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in the label - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-rtr.tls=true"

This fixed the issue for me